# Google Webmaster Tools - Property for example.com/city?

Tags: google-search-console

my page runs at `https://example.com/city`. The user who enters example.com in the browser will automatically be redirected to `https://example.com/city`.

Which properties do I have to add to Google Webmaster Tools? Do I add:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com

https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

And does Google understand that everybody is redirected to /city/ or do I have to add these URLs as well as the above to Webmaster Tools? In complete:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com

https://example.com
https://www.example.com

http://example.com/city
http://www.example.com/city

https://example.com/city
https://www.example.com/city
```

This seems a bit to much? Can somebody please enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: You should be using just one, HTTPS or HTTP. As well, you should be using just one, www or non-www. In the end, you are only going to worry about one, for example, HTTPS with www. The /city thing does not come into play. Ignore it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting all version of website in Google search console, will not make you in trouble, so feel free to add all type of properties.

I suggest to submit this one properties first - `https://example.com/city` - And submit your sitemap to this property, so all crawling, indexing and ranking data will display into this property.

Additionally, you can add your main website `https://example.com`, but don't submit sitemap to this property, because may be in future, you will going to add another city like `https://example.com/anotherCity`.

If `example.com/city` and `www.example.com/city` automatically redirect to `https://example.com/city`, then you don't need to add other properties, but adding other properties will not cost you anything, **just focus on one property, and submit your sitemap to that one only.**